# Find shortest path through points in 2D plane

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, shortest-path

I've got following problem:

Given the set of points P = { (x1, y1), (x2, y2), ..., (xn, yn) } on plane, find the shortest path with following properties:

- it starts from the left most point L in P (with the smallest x coordinate)
- it goes to the right most point R in (with the largest x coordinate), through points with increasing x coordinate
- then it goes back from R to L through points with decreasing x coordinate
- it visits all points from P
- we may assume that that all points have different x coordinates.
- Aditionaly I've assume that every point can be visited only once (but I'm not sure if it doesn't follow from above properties).

I've developed following algorithm:

```
1. sort points in P by the x coordinate
2. start two paths in the left most point L
3. for each p in P:
4.     extend path that has last point closest to p
5. connect shorter path with R with edge X
```

But it proved to be wrong. Paths can intersect and when they are intersecting, there is always better path, that can be constructed by switching endpoints of intersecting segments. How to solve it?

Comment: i.e., you want to find a minimum-length [bitonic tour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_tour). Wikipedia suggests that this appeared as an exercise in CLRS, which jives with my memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David Eisenstat mentions, you require the shortest bitonic tour covering each point.

This can be done through dynamic programming in O(n^2) time.

Let `Pij (1 <= i <= j <= n)` be a bitonic path from point `pi` to `pj` such that the path starts from `pi`, goes strictly left to `p1`, then goes strictly right to `pj`, in the process covering all the points to the left of `pj`.

Let `d[i,j]` be the length of the shortest such path from `i` to `j`.

```
Note that d[1,2] = dist(p1,p2)
d[1,3] = d[1,2] + dist(p2,p3).
d[i,j] = d[i,j-1] + dist(j-1,j) for i < j-1.
d[j-1,j] = min( d[k,j-1] + dist(k,j) ) for 1 <= k < j-1
```

You can find `d[n,n]` using the above recurrence relation.

Building this 2-D matrix takes O(n^2) time

Comment: It's possible to get by with O(n) space.